# Set Background color for a selected item in a Select option (multiple)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to change the background color of the selected items in a listbox (select multiple options).

I tried with css... I tried with  JavaScript... and with jquery... I really don't know what happen!! But I'm unable to find the answer :_(.

I read at least 10 questions in this forum.. and I tried all the proposed solutions but I only can change the background of the complete list... not the selected items. The only way I found is to use an unordered list with clickable list items instead if my select - option ... but I'm working with a form, and I want to send to the server the selected items in the traditional way.

Comment: welcomew to SO. Please edit your question and add some code so that we can see what you have tried?

Comment: The selection color is a OS preference.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, though I may be wrong.

Comment: You can set style properties on option elements in most browsers, but not in older IE versions.

Answer (score 7):

This will change the background color of the selected option

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('option').css('background', 'none');
    $('option:selected').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
}).change();
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/TxbVt/1/

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it wants to play ball:

```
<style>

::selection {
   background: #FF0000; /* Safari */
   }
::-moz-selection {
   background: #FF0000; /* Firefox */
}
</style>

<select multiple="true">
<option><span style="background:FF0000;">One</span></option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
</select>

<p>This is text.</p>
```

This doesn't suprise me. In my experience widgets are generally resistant to such styling. Rolling your own, like in Hussein's approach, looks like your only way out.

Answer (score 1):

#### JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('your-select').onchange = function() {

    var options = this.getElementsByTagName('option'),
        selectedClassName = 'selected';

    for (var i = 0, length = options.length; i < length; i++) {
        var option = options[i],
            className = option.className;

        if (i == this.selectedIndex) {
            option.className += selectedClassName;
        } else {
            option.className = (' ' + className + ' ').replace(new RegExp('\\s' + selectedClassName + '\\s'), '');
        }
    }
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3tev/).

#### CSS

```
#your-select option.selected {
    background: red;   
}
```

Comment: what about IE8? only on ff and chrome works fine your script on IE8 does not work.

Comment: @mcmwhfy What's the problem in IE8? Error?

Comment: on IE8 the selection remain in the select box and not in the list (<option> tag).

Comment: @mcmwhfy Can you put an example of it not working on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: check this print screen: http://postimage.org/image/lrj00um9n/

Comment: and this is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/TxbVt/486/