# Is it possible to change the select color for form elements like a multiple select?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I want to change the selection color of a multiple select element. I'm not talking about the background color in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640355/set-background-color-for-a-selected-item-in-a-select-option-multiple) answer, as this only changes the background color of the selected option (the selection color is still visible on top of that).

I'm aware this color is determined by the settings of your hardware, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857846/change-form-select-multiple-highlight-color), but I was wondering if there was any way other than changing your system settings that can override this setting.

Comment: The answer there says "it cannot be overridden in CSS3"

Comment: I saw that, but was wondering if there was any other way than CSS to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replicate the element with divs and such and program the logic with JS. This would give you complete control over appearance.

It's also not a great idea to ask your user to learn how to use new simple UI elements. You should consider the mobile compatibility, and maintenance of this code too.

Comment: This is a solution that could work, thanks for the help and I'm gonna try this :)